# How to get the text values

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

m having a textfields for name and age when i click the submit button those values should be passed to another page how can i do that?
NAME
AGE

SUBMIT

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

       {

            litText.Text = Request.Form["tbName"] + ": " + Request.Form["tbAge"];
        }
    }

    public Default3()
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Show your code

Comment: when i click the submit button the values entered should be displayed in a different webpage

Answer (score 4):

In .aspx file:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txbAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox id="txbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

In aspx.cs file:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string age = txbAge.Text;
  string name = txbName.Text;
  string url = string.Format("~/anotherPage.aspx?age={0}&name={1}", age, name);
  Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

In second .aspx file:

```
<aspx:Label id="lblAge" runat="server"></aspx:Label>
<aspx:Label id="lblName" runat="server"></aspx:Label>
```

In second .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string age = string.Empty;
  string name = string.Empty;

  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["age"]))
    age = Request.QueryString["age"];
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["name "]))
    age = Request.QueryString["name "];

  lblAge.Text = age;
  lblName.Text = name;

}
```

And this is the way how to get these values on another page in querystring.

Mariusz

Comment: and then on the other page you can pick up these values using `Request.QueryString["age"]` and `Request.QueryString["name"]`

Comment: Right I forgot to write this.

Comment: Add it to your answer. Make it the complete article :-)

Comment: Server Error in '/uploadpdf' Application.
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: He can also use session if he does not desire to expose values in query string(might be overkill), but a very good and detailed answer.

Comment: He can even write it to database and then get them from it :) but querystring is the simplest way to explain, because you can see stored data. Ofcourse that was only my opinion